# Can't add authtoken to "ngrok"

Tags: networking, ngrok, kali-linux

I'm new to Kali Linux and recently I tried to install ngrok, it worked perfectly but now for some reason it doesn't. I tried to create a new Authtoken and add it on Kali but it always says "`ERROR:  Unrecognized command: config`". I've searched everywhere but I can't find a solution, please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The documentation is wrong. See the answer below - that'll work.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

had the same problem too just a couple of hours ago fixed it by typing ngrok authtoken xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx (replace the x with the authcode from the ngrok dashboard)